# uniform initialization of temporary reference

Tags: c++11, gcc, clang++

consider the following code

```
int x; 
using intref = int&; 
intref w{x}; // A 
intref{x}; // B
```

now, line A compiles correctly both in clang and gcc ( it didn't as of 
c++11, defect fixed in c++14 AFAIK )

the problem is line B: clang treats it the way one would expect 
( a temporary reference is bound to x ) whereas gcc 4.9 treat it in 
the old defected way ( a temporary of type int is created and bound to 
the reference, resulting in a compiler error ).

Who's right here ? thank you

Comment: Even clang gives a compiler error for me.

Comment: [CWG 1521](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_active.html#1521)